# PHP script for optimizing loading CSV data

Tags: php, algorithm, csv, optimization

My PHP script look like this and it works, it simulate like it is join from SQL query, but it's not optimize and everything is loaded in RAM, can someone help me how to optimize and to load in RAM only necessary rows and columns from other CSV, based on left side of "join" of first CSV file? Also if it able to simulate WHERE clause, then it should look through less data, true?

```
<pre>
    <?php
    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

    $city = array_map('str_getcsv', file('a.csv'));
    $table = array_map('str_getcsv', file('c.csv'));

    function left_join_array($left, $right, $left_join_on, $right_join_on){
        $final= array();

        foreach($left AS $k => $v){
            $final[$k] = $v;
            foreach($right AS $kk => $vv){
                if($v[$left_join_on] == $vv[$right_join_on]){
                    foreach($vv AS $key => $val)
                        $final[$k][$key] = $val; 
                }
            }
        }
       return $final;
    }
    $new_table = left_join_array($table, $city, 4, 0);
    print_r($new_table);
```

My a.csv file looks like this:

```
70106,Belgrade
70114,New York
70122,London
70220,Moscow
```

My c.csv file looks like this:

```
id | id_continent       | id_country | zip_code | id_city
 1      Europe             England     WC2N 5DU    70122
 2      North America        USA        10004      70114
 3      Europe             Belgrade     11000      70106
 4      Europe              Moscow      101000     70220
```

Comment: how big is this file? Are you running out of memory? If not, why does it matter? RAM is cheap.

Comment: @ADyson it have 2 milion of rows, for performance i would like to load only necessary data, and to make script faster, to work only with data that needs

Comment: you can't load "only the data that you need" into memory because you have to load the data into RAM (from the disk) before you can read it and check whether you need it. Catch-22. Of course you could try and read each line of the file individually, and then discard it if you don't need it, but you'd have to test whether that's actually more efficient than pulling the whole file from disk in one operation, given the number of rows.

Comment: @ADyson of course it will be more efficient, PHP arrays are developed to be EXTREMELY inefficient. His code might work well in C++ but not in PHP

Comment: @thelmuxkriovar Ok but that has to be weighed against the cost of repeated disk I/O (to read 2 million rows individually) though, surely? Like I said, worth testing.

Comment: @ADyson fair enough

Answer (score 0):

Never ever load big files in your ram. What you think is a good idea will always turn out to be a bad idea. The first optimization you can do is using a generator for $table e.g.:

```
function getTable($file) {
    $h = fopen($file, "r");
    while (($line = fgets($h)) !== false) {
        yield str_getcsv($line);
    }
    fclose($h);
}
```

Second your left_join_array function is an issue, it's speed is `O(n^3)`, very slow, and as far as memory goes you're allocating a ton of it as well, but I'll need more information about what you're trying to do with the data before we can talk about how to optimize that.

EDIT: Based on your comment here's my edited answer.

MySQL will always be faster than anything you can write in a few minutes, especially if you don't have any knowledge about how RDBMS work. You can simulate it as much as you want but MySQL should be at least an order of magnitude faster; MySQL's join algorithm is `O((n*m) log(n*m))`, your algorithm is exponentially slower (literally).

If this is just a test for the purpose of learning to code or whatever, the best you can do is in that case you should just use the generator function above for both $city and $table.

Comment: i want to compare time execution of SQL query in MySQL and PHP script time execution on same tables(csv files), so i am simulating SQL query to get most near result with this algorithm, but to be most close, it need to be optimize, and maybe to use also where clause to cut in the start some data?

Comment: there wasn't enough space in the comments to answer this question, so please checkout my edited answer.

Comment: ok, I appreciate your answer, i don't think i can write faster db engine than MySQL, that is not purpose, purpose is testing. But my question is how to optimize my existing code, how to make to load only part that is needed or how to cut data with simulating where clause in algorithm.Is it even possible to do something like that?

Comment: It is. As I said in my answer, you can use the generator function above for both your values and the speed should increase a lot.

Comment: ok, can you write if it's not problem? i don't get it, i need to add two function and to pass it to my existing function?

Comment: `$city = getTable("a.csv");` and `$table = getTable('c.csv');`

Comment: ok, what to $handle, it report fatal error when i pass resource $h,  and nested foreach report error, 'Cannot traverse an already closed generator'

Comment: oops $handle should've been $h and the foreach only reports an error because of the first error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155281/discussion-between-mpetrovic-and-thelmuxkriovar).